# Margins on parts of QML TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml, styling

In a QML TextEdit, I'm trying to have parts of the text indented and/or formatted otherwise (force uppercase, italic, bold, etc...) while other parts have different styling (screenplay formatting). My initial idea was to wrap every part into a `<p class = 'dialogue'>...</p>` or `<span class = 'bold'>...</span>` and then have a CSS file with margins etc. set accordingly.

However, I see no way to set a stylesheet for TextEdits (there's a function `setDefaultStylesheet` for QTextDocuments, but its properties can't be modified). Additionally, there is the question if e.g. CSS's `margin-left: 50%` would work correctly. From what I have seen, CSS does not seem to be supported for most of QML (although some discussions have hinted at partial support for TextEdits).

Styling only in QML would be okay, too, though I don't see how this would work for parts of the TextEdits contents.

Is there a way to make this concept work or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Have you already read `http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html`?

Comment: @sk2212 Thanks, although I've read that document before and I haven't yet found anything that can be used for individually formatting each line (or word or block of text). I can only find functionality for styling the whole document or making passages of text bold/italic/underlined.